# How to transform row data into columns?

Tags: sql, database

I have this data from a sql table, but do not know how to put into the table structure below. What is the best method for converting the data to that structure?

```
2011/07/13  Wednesday   10:00   1       
2011/07/13  Wednesday   10:30   1       
2011/07/13  Wednesday   11:00   0   
... 
2011/07/15  Friday      10:00   1       
2011/07/15  Friday      10:30   0       
2011/07/15  Friday      11:00   0       
2011/07/15  Friday      11:30   1   
... 
2011/07/16  Saturday    09:00   0       
2011/07/16  Saturday    09:30   1       
2011/07/16  Saturday    10:00   1   
...       
2011/07/17  Sunday      10:00   1       
2011/07/17  Sunday      10:30   0       
2011/07/17  Sunday      11:00   0       
2011/07/17  Sunday      11:30   1   
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RDBMS doesn't support PIVOT, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
  TIME,
  (SELECT FLAG FROM SCHED S WHERE DATE = '7/13/2011' AND TIME = SCHED.TIME) AS [7/13/2011],
  (SELECT FLAG FROM SCHED S WHERE DATE = '7/14/2011' AND TIME = SCHED.TIME) AS [7/14/2011]
  ... other date columns ...
FROM            
   SCHED
```

This is assuming your table has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHED
(
    [DATE] date,
    TIME char(5),
    FLAG tinyint
)
```

And you probably want to use the date/time functions to calculate dates relative to the current date in your subqueries rather than hard-code them like I have, but you get the idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the pivot operator (MS-SQL)

See here: 
[How to transform a datatable to a ReportingService-like matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469897/how-to-transform-a-datatable-to-a-reportingservice-like-matrix)

Comment: Cannot use this in sql 2000 - any other solutions?

Comment: You could try to emulate pivot with the 'case when then else' clause, as in MySQL.